# hiding a div from users view

Tags: php, jquery

I want to return true  when the number of rows in a table is more than one and show a div with jquery as shown in the jquery code .In addition return false  when the number of rows is zero and hide a div as shown in the code below.The php code is executing and returning a correct value but the jquery code is neither showing or hiding a div.I need to show a div when the value returned is true and hide a div when the value returned is false;

```
**php code** php code for retrieving the number of rows from a table


<?php
    require'php/connection.php';//a file for connecting to the database
    $user_name=getUserField('user_name');//function for getting the name of the user in session

    $query="select `order_id` from `inbox` where `buyer_name`='$user_name'";
    $query_run=mysql_query($query);
    $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query_run);
    if($num_rows >= 1) {
        return true;
    } else if($num_rows == 0) {
        return false;
    }
?>
```

**jquery code** Jquery code for either hiding or showing a div

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post('php/ManNotify.php',{},function(data){
        if(true) {
            $('#notify').show();
        } else if(false) {
            $('#notify').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: $('#notify').toggle(data)

Answer (score 1):

Do you realize your if statement reads,

```
if(true) ..
else if(false) ...
```

The hide will never execute.  Is this your problem?

Comment: When you write if(true) the code in the brackets that follow WILL ALWAYS execute.  I suspect what you want is something like if( data == true ) ..

Answer (score 1):

When using AJAX calls with PHP, you should `echo` the value rather than return it. Modify your PHP code like so:

```
<?php
    require'php/connection.php';//a file for connecting to the database
    $user_name=getUserField('user_name');//function for getting the name of the user in session

    $query="select `order_id` from `inbox` where `buyer_name`='$user_name'";
    $query_run=mysql_query($query);
    $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query_run);
    if($num_rows >= 1){
        echo json_encode(array("status" => true));
    } else if($num_rows == 0) {
        echo json_encode(array("status" => false));
    }
    exit;
?>
```

You'll also need to modify your JavaScript accordingly. Right now, `if(true)` will always execute on the return. Modify it like so:

```
// Shorthand for $(document).ready
$(function(){
    $.post('php/ManNotify.php',{}, function(data) {
        // JavaScript truthy/falsy will take care of the statement
        if(data.status) {
            $('#notify').show();
        } else {
            $('#notify').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

As *@mplungjan* points out in the comments below, the JavaScript could be simplified in the callback to be the following: `$('#notify').toggle(data.status);`. The resulting JavaScript would be:

```
// Shorthand for $(document).ready
$(function(){
    $.post('php/ManNotify.php',{}, function(data) {
        $('#notify').toggle(data.status);
    });
});
```

Thanks to *@mplungjan* for the suggestion.

Comment: $('#notify').toggle(data.status)

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks. I've edited that into the question and tagged your name for credit.

Comment: @user3800343 Ok, let's dive deeper into _"not working"_. What is it or is it not doing? Are you getting any errors? If so, are they PHP or JavaScript errors?

Comment: The  php code is executing returning a correct value butthe jquery code is neither hiding nor showing the code but when you place the $("#notify").show() above the post,the div is showing

Comment: @user3800343 Hmm. If you would, add `console.log(data);` as the first statement in the callback function. Then open your console `<F12>` and see the value that was logged. This is to check and make sure your data structure looks correct (and to make sure I didn't miss something on my end).

Comment: Have never used console just demonstate it to me because the jquery coding is not giving me any error alert

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what to demonstrate. The code I included in the previous comment is the exact code you need to log data to the console. If you're using IE, make sure the console is open, and then reload the page. IE doesn't automatically connect the console.

Comment: `window.console && console.log(data);` will handle that problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.post('php/ManNotify.php',{},function(data){
    if(data == 'true'){
    $('#notify').show();
    }else if(data == 'false')
    {
    $('#notify').hide();
    }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.post('php/ManNotify.php',{},function(data){
    if(data == "true"){
    $('#notify').show();
    }else if(data == "false")
    {
    $('#notify').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1. The server-side code. Returning boolean TRUE or FALSE this way will only render the page blank.
2. The jQuery code logic is wrong: `if(true){` case will always be executed (because the value is, well, always true).

A very simple fix would be (untested):

```
if($num_rows >= 1){
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Then, in the JS:

```
$.post('php/ManNotify.php', function(data){
    if(data === 'true'){
        $('#notify').show();
    } else {
        $('#notify').hide();
    }
});
```

Note that this is not optimized.

Comment: What does your `data` look like? Try putting `console.log(data)` in the success function.

Comment: Please can you do a bit of illustration,have never used console before,please

Comment: This comment box wouldn't be enough... Read the [Google Dev Tool Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index) here.

Comment: I have used console and the code is not giving me any error.